# what does snarl of brambles mean

Tags: word-meaning

following this [article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/print)

I don't understand what is snarl of bramble from

> If you draw many loops containing a large number of points, most of
>   the loops will overlap and tangle like a snarl of brambles.

from the context, they are talking about sets of points that intersect each other.  snarl means like contorted? and brambles is like brushes?

Comment: Would you have had the same comprehension problem with *...the loops will overlap and snarl like a [**tangle of thorns***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tangle+of+thorns%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNQDXj_VgOmQWQ1DpEpsFyy8XnOM3w:1577637780891&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMl47cptvmAhVGPFAKHYeaCNgQpwUIIQ&biw=1598&bih=796&dpr=1.13*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [snarl](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snarl) means as verbs

1 : to cause to become knotted and intertwined : TANGLE

2 : to make excessively complicated

Snarl means as a noun is

1 : a tangle especially of hairs or thread : KNOT
2 : a tangled situation
traffic snarls

Bramble is a kind of plant.

Snarl of brambles means that a situation branches of brambles are intertwined or knotted.

Comment: Bramble is a thorny plant which tends to root wherever the branches touch the ground.

Answer (score 3):

These brambles are snarled (tangled together). They are a snarl of brambles.

[image]